# Is a process PID guaranteed to stay the same as long as the process doesn't die?

Tags: linux, process, pid

I'm doing some simulation work with Linux, and the code I'm working on right now only works under the assumption that, once a process has been assigned a PID by the kernel, that PID will remain the same until the process is killed. I would assume this is true but since I'm kind of new to the Linux world I just want to see if there are any special circumstances I ought to be aware of. Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, it's guaranteed. Process will have the same PID even if its image will be replaced with another one by [exec](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exec_(operating_system)) system call.

Comment: Well, a malicious programmer can break the guarantee, but this is generally true of well behaved programs.

Comment: I can't agree with you, since `fork` creates **new** process with same image it's naturally that this **new** process has another PID value. In case from your answer I would say that _program_ changes its PID (by changing its process), but not the process (and the question is about processes).

Comment: That is, of course, strictly true, but that simply reflects the definition of "process" that the OS uses. The user will see a continuity of *state* with a changing number, and if she was counting on the presence/absence of the PID to determine if some state was present on the machines this would be a problem. That's why I called the behavior malicious.

Comment: Do you have a source for the claim that the PID doesn't change?

Comment: @MartinThoma, all [man credentials](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/credentials.7.html#DESCRIPTION) says about PID is that it's assigned on process creation and is preserved across `execve()`. Since PID is assigned only on process creation, persistence of PID follows.

Answer (score 11):

Well...***mostly***.

As [other posters have said](https://superuser.com/a/457648/1711) any particular process will retain it's PID indefinitely. Even through one or more instances of `exec`.

**However**, a programmer who wished to evade that guarantee on a unix box would have no trouble at all. He would simple `fork`, ignore HUP signals in the daughter and then kill the mother process. The result of which would be the daughter carrying on with a new PID and give the appearance that the process changed it's PID.

Comment: Just to clarify: If I write the process and I don't want the PID to change, it will not change. There is basically no chance I accidentally do something that changes the PID.

Comment: Do you have a source for the claim that the PID doesn't change?

Answer (score 4):

PID in Linux and Windows are unique to that process.  PIDs will never change.

Comment: Do you have a source for the claim that the PID doesn't change?